# Multiple lookup set

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I need a data structure, and I'm unsure of what to choose. Fundamentally, my need is similar to `std::set`, except I need to look up according to multiple different comparators over the same data at the same time.

Right now I've decided to go for some kludge- a `std::map<float, std::unordered_set<T>>` and then a `std::unordered_map<T, std::unordered_set<T>*>`. This should permit O(log N) lookup for a `float` and O(1) lookup/removal for a `T`.

Are there any better data structures to use? This has "hack" written all over it.

As an aside, this code *is* fairly performance critical, so something fast would be very appreciated.

Edit: I've been poking with `boost::multi_index` and here's what I've got so far:

```
boost::multi_index_container<
    NodeType,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>, decltype(node_comparator)>,
        boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>
    >
> open_set(
    boost::make_tuple(node_comparator)
);
```

where `node_comparator` is an in_scope lambda. But attempting to compile it results in some glorious errors.

```
1>d:\backups\code\boost_1_47_0\boost\multi_index\detail\node_type.hpp(56): error C2903: 'node_class' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template
1>          d:\backups\code\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\plain\apply_wrap.hpp(49) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_applier::apply<IndexSpecifierIterator,Super>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              IndexSpecifierIterator=boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector2<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>,Wide::Sim::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>>,0>,
1>              Super=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<NodeType,std::allocator<NodeType>>>
1>          ]
1>          d:\backups\code\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\plain\bind.hpp(207) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::apply_wrap2<F,T1,T2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_applier,
1>              T1=boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector2<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>,Wide::Sim::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>>,0>,
1>              T2=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<NodeType,std::allocator<NodeType>>>
1>          ]
1>          d:\backups\code\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\plain\apply_wrap.hpp(49) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::bind2<F,T1,T2>::apply<U1,U2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_applier,
1>              T1=boost::mpl::_2,
1>              T2=boost::mpl::_1,
1>              U1=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<NodeType,std::allocator<NodeType>>>,
1>              U2=boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector2<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>,Wide::Sim::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>>,0>
1>          ]
1>          d:\backups\code\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\plain\apply.hpp(63) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::apply_wrap2<F,T1,T2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=boost::mpl::bind2<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_applier,boost::mpl::_2,boost::mpl::_1>,
1>              T1=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<NodeType,std::allocator<NodeType>>>,
1>              T2=boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector2<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>,Wide::Sim::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>>,0>
1>          ]
1>          d:\backups\code\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\plain\reverse_iter_fold_impl.hpp(82) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::apply2<F,T1,T2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=boost::mpl::bind2<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_applier,boost::mpl::_2,boost::mpl::_1>,
1>              T1=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<NodeType,std::allocator<NodeType>>>,
1>              T2=boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector2<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>,Wide::Sim::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>>,0>
1>          ]
1>          d:\backups\code\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\reverse_iter_fold.hpp(43) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::aux::reverse_iter_fold_impl<N,First,Last,State,BackwardOp,ForwardOp>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              N=2,
1>              First=boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector2<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>,Wide::Sim::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>>,0>,
1>              Last=boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector2<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>,Wide::Sim::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>>,2>,
1>              State=boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<NodeType,std::allocator<NodeType>>,
1>              BackwardOp=boost::mpl::bind2<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_applier,boost::mpl::_2,boost::mpl::_1>,
1>              ForwardOp=boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::arg<1>>
1>          ]
1>          d:\backups\code\boost_1_47_0\boost\multi_index\detail\node_type.hpp(70) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::reverse_iter_fold<Sequence,State,BackwardOp>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Sequence=boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>,Wide::Sim::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>>,
1>              State=boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<NodeType,std::allocator<NodeType>>,
1>              BackwardOp=boost::mpl::bind2<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_applier,boost::mpl::_2,boost::mpl::_1>
1>          ]
1>          d:\backups\code\boost_1_47_0\boost\multi_index_container.hpp(75) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::multi_index_node_type<Value,IndexSpecifierList,Allocator>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Value=NodeType,
1>              IndexSpecifierList=boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>,Wide::Sim::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>>,
1>              Allocator=std::allocator<NodeType>
1>          ]
1>          c:\repo\render\render\sim\simcontext.cpp(264) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<Value,IndexSpecifierList>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Value=NodeType,
1>              IndexSpecifierList=boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>,Wide::Sim::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<NodeType>>>
1>          ]
```

This is just the first; there are many, but I'm well aware of Visual Studio's propensity to let one error cause 9999999 more.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html doesn't work for you?

Comment: `float` is not a good key type, as it doesn't have a strict weak ordering.

Comment: @Kerrek: Isn't that only true if you involve NaNs and such? I'm strictly in R.

Comment: @dirkgently: I've been poking it. Now I've got ALL THE COMPILATION ERRORS.

Comment: @DeadMG: `float` is okay as long as your values as well spaced (or you blow them up to avoid comparison issues). Can you post a few of those errors you've hit with `multi_index`?

Comment: @dirkgently: It's a fairly impenetrable error, deep in MPL metaprogramming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multi_index` was the winner. Unfortunately `dirkgently` posted as comment, not answer, or I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to use a `weak_ptr` in your `unordered_set`, and `shared_ptr` for your elements. When you destruct the element, a NULL `weak_ptr` is left behind. You would need some way to garbage collect those NULL `weak_ptr` entries in your container, but that cost is likely easily amortized. This way, you avoid needing to use a second index at all.